# restore vim session without opening [no name] buffer

Tags: vim

I use the following viminfo setting in my .vimrc to restore my last session.

```
set viminfo='10,\"100,:20,%,n~/.viminfo
```

It works as expected, except for one detail: When I start vim with no command line parameters, it restores all my buffers, but it also opens a [no name] buffer with the vim version number, etc. and starts me in this [no name] buffer.  I then `:bd` this buffer and continue on my way.

How can I restore my session without opening the [no name] buffer?

I tried replacing my entire .vimrc with a single `set viminfo=...` line like the one above, but the problem persists.

I am using vim 7.3.  I am not using gvim.

Comment: Hmm, using the same `viminfo` config I can't duplicate this. I am not getting the extra splash buffer.

Comment: I also have `set shortmess=filnxtToOI`  (`I` is supposed to disable the shortmess entirely)

Comment: I added your shortmess settings, but that didn't fix it.  I also added version info above.

Comment: I took everything out of my .vimrc except the `set viminfo=...` and that didn't fix it either.

Comment: Have you thought about using `:mksession`?

Comment: @Peter Rincker That works -- the splash screen goes away, but I wanted it to be automatic.

Answer (score 1):

put this line in your _vimrc:

```
set shortmess+=I
```

Tested this out successfully in vim on Windows 7